# Hide element in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor to show some html that I have stored in my DB.
But I don't want to show all the elements while loading the content.
The problem is CKEditor ignores style like "display:none".

Any suggestions?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

CKEditor does support style like display: none but there is an option that I have to set to true.

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```